# How to add props in react for styles?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple section in which I want to change the width dynamically

Here is section

```
<div className="form-control">
            <Formats>
                {styles.map(style => <ButtonStyled type="button" active={style.id === styleId} onClick={() => setStyleId(style.id)} key={`button-${style.name}`}>{style.name}</ButtonStyled>)}
                {activeStyle && <FormatsContent>
                    <FormatsDescription>{activeStyle.desciption}</FormatsDescription>
                    <Proportions>
                        {activeStyle.proportions.map(x => <Proportion onClick={() => setProportion(x.proportion)} active={proportion === x.proportion} width={x.width} height={x.height} key={`proportion-${x.proportion}`}>{x.proportionLabel}</Proportion>)}
                    </Proportions> 
                </FormatsContent>}
            </Formats>
        </div>
```

Here is style

```
const Formats = styled.div`
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding:12px;
    background-color: ${gray.brightest};
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    & select {
    height: 31px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 12px;
    }
`;
```

Now I want to add props to check if width is full or not `isFullWidth:true/false`

and on styles to use it like this,

```
   const Formats = styled.div`
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding:12px;
    background-color: ${gray.brightest};
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: ${props => props.isFullWidth ? '100%' : '59%'}
    & select {
    height: 31px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 12px;
    }
`;
```

What do I need to change to achieve what I want?

Comment: Are you using theming?

Comment: am using styled-components

Comment: I know you're using styled components. The solution you described (styles interpolation based on props) can only be used for theming in styled components. https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: am using theming do u know the soultion?

Comment: @user9964622 has my solution worked for you?

Comment: @user9964622 has any of the solutions worked for you? Consider accepting the solution that has worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

The Format component should have `isFullWidth` prop holding either `true` or `false` as value as shown below:

The example below will give a `100%` width

```
<Format isFullWidth ={true}>

</Format>
```

And this one will give a `59%` width

```
<Format isFullWidth ={false}>

</Format>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is enough to pass the prop to the component and keep the last style you posted:

So it should be

```js
<Formats isFullWidth>
...
</Formats>
```

EDIT: wrong prop name